# Close a Suitelet window on submit

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to use window.close() on a suitelet as part of the post response.

The suitelet is a pop up that was opened from a client script.

This is the relevant part of the client script:

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(["N/record", "N/url", "N/currentRecord"], function (
  record,
  url,
  currentRecord
) {
  /**
   * @param {ClientScriptContext.pageInit} context
   * @param {ClientScriptContext.onclick_callforSuitelet} context
   */
  function pageInit() {}
  function onclick_callforSuitelet() {
    var record = currentRecord.get();
    var recordId = record.id;
    var recordType = record.type;
    log.debug("recId", recordId);
    log.debug("recType", recordType);

    //this is the script id on the script record for the suitelet (not the deployment)
    var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: "customscript_suitelet_notes",
      //this is the id from the deployment record for the suitelet
      deploymentId: "customdeploy_suitelet_notes",
      params: { recordId: recordId, recordType: recordType },
    });
    window.open(
      suiteletURL,
      "_blank",
      "popup=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=1000,height=1000"
    );
```

I am getting the following error message: "org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined.".

I can't find anything online on how to define the 'window' (i.e. the current window).

Alternatively, I am thinking of adding a onclick event that automatically closes the window on submit. I can't seem to find anything on how I would go about doing that (which APIs to use) or whether that is even possible?

So my questions are around:

1. How do I define the 'window' in a server side script?
2. If the submit button on the suitelet was added using

```js
    form.addSubmitButton({label:submit})
```

is it possible to add a function to the submit button so that in addition to saving the record. the window can be closed after a specified number of seconds? (i.e. adding a setTimeout method?)

Would I need a custom button to achieve this instead of the form.addSubmit button?

I have tried various methods though am having no joy since I am not even sure any of this is possible to do.

Edit: I have tried creating a new client script with the window.close function on pageinit and attaching this client script to the suitelet response per below

```js
    /**  *@NApiVersion 2.x  
     * *@NScriptType Suitelet  
     * */
    
    define(["N/ui/serverWidget", "N/log", "N/record", "N/url"], function (
      serverWidget,
      log,
      record,
      url
    ) {
      /**    * @param {SuiteletContext.onRequest} context    */
    
      function onRequest(context) {
        if (context.request.method === "GET") {
          var invoice_id = parseInt(context.request.parameters.recordId);
          var form = serverWidget.createForm({ id: "notes", title: "Notes" });
    
          var customerGroup = form.addFieldGroup({
            id: "customerDetails",
            label: "Customer Details",
          });
          customerGroup.isSingleColumn = false;
          form.addSubmitButton({ label: "Submit" });
          var select = form.addField({
            id: "custpage_source",
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: "Source of Communication",
            container: "customerDetails",
          });
          select.addSelectOption({ value: 1, text: "Phone" });
          select.addSelectOption({ value: 2, text: "Email" });
          select.addSelectOption({ value: 3, text: "Website Contact Form" });
          select.addSelectOption({ value: 4, text: "Other" });
          form.addPageLink({
            type: serverWidget.FormPageLinkType.CROSSLINK,
            title: "Invoice",
            url:
              "https://<accountid>.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/custinvc.nl?id=" +
              invoice_id,
          });
          var parentTransaction = form.addField({
            id: "custpage_parent_transaction",
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: "Parent Transaction",
            container: "customerDetails",
          });
          parentTransaction.addSelectOption({
            value: invoice_id,
            text: invoice_id,
          });
          context.response.writePage(form);
          function getBaseUrl() {
            return url.resolveRecord({ recordType: record.Type.INVOICE });
          }
        } else {
          var delimiter = /\u0001/;
          var sourceField = context.request.parameters.custpage_source;
          var parentField = context.request.parameters.custpage_parent_transaction;
          var invoiceRecord = record.load({
            type: record.Type.INVOICE,
            id: parentField,
          });
          log.debug("parent record", invoiceRecord);
          var recObj = record.create({ type: "customrecord_user_notes" });
          recObj.setValue({ fieldId: "custrecord_source", value: sourceField });
          recObj.setValue({
            fieldId: "custrecord_parent_transaction",
            value: parentField,
          });
          var userNote = recObj.save({}); 
    
          var notesFieldUpdate = record.submitFields({
            type: record.Type.INVOICE,
            id: parentField,
            values: {
              custbody_notes_check:
                "<span style='color:#e74c3c;'>Check Notes</span>",
            },
          });
          log.debug("notesfield", notesFieldUpdate);
    
        //  context.response.write("Note Created");
          var form_close = serverWidget.createForm({ id: "notes_close", title: "Notes" });
          form_close.clientScriptFileId = 2637;
          context.response.writePage(form_close)
    
         
        }
      }
      return { onRequest: onRequest };
    });
```

The form_close page is being created on submit though the client script function is not triggering
[image]

This is the client script:

```js
    /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType ClientScript
     */
    define([], function () {
      /**
       * @param {ClientScriptContext.pageInit} context
       */
      function pageInit(context) {
    alert("client script pageinit triggered")
        window.close();
      }
    
      return {
        pageInit: pageInit,
      };
    });
```

Am I missing something on the client script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the client script to trigger on the post response of the suitelet.

Instead, I have found this is the only way to close the window after the suitelet has been submitted

```js
    /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType Suitelet
     */
    define(["N/ui/serverWidget", "N/log", "N/record", "N/url"], function (
      serverWidget,
      log,
      record,
      url
    ) {
      /**
       * @param {SuiteletContext.onRequest} context
       */
      function onRequest(context) {
        if (context.request.method === "GET") {
          // Section One - Forms
          var invoice_id = parseInt(context.request.parameters.recordId);
    
          var form = serverWidget.createForm({
            id: "notes",
            title: "Notes",
          });
          //form.clientScriptFileId=5110;
          var customerGroup = form.addFieldGroup({
            id: "customerDetails",
            label: "Customer Details",
          });
          customerGroup.isSingleColumn = false;
    
          form.addSubmitButton({
            label: "Submit",
          });
    
          var select = form.addField({
            id: "custpage_source",
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: "Source of Communication",
            container: "customerDetails",
          });
          //the value is the internal id of the option under customisation>lists,records and forms>lists>'source of communication' list
          select.addSelectOption({
            value: 1,
            text: "Phone",
          });
    
          select.addSelectOption({
            value: 2,
            text: "Email",
          });
    
          select.addSelectOption({
            value: 3,
            text: "Website Contact Form",
          });
    
          select.addSelectOption({
            value: 4,
            text: "Other",
          });
    
          form.addPageLink({
            type: serverWidget.FormPageLinkType.CROSSLINK,
            title: "Invoice",
            url:
              "https://<accountid>.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/custinvc.nl?id=" +
              invoice_id,
          });
    
          var parentTransaction = form.addField({
            id: "custpage_parent_transaction",
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: "Parent Transaction",
            container: "customerDetails",
          });
    
          parentTransaction.addSelectOption({
            value: invoice_id,
            text: invoice_id,
          });
    
          // form.updateDefaultValues({
          //   custpage_recordurl:
          //     "https://<accountid>.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/custinvc.nl?id=" +
          //     recId,
          // });
          context.response.writePage(form);
    
          function getBaseUrl() {
            return url.resolveRecord({
              recordType: record.Type.INVOICE,
            });
          }
          // Section Two - Tabs - See "Steps for Adding a Tab to a Form"
          // Section Three - Sublist - See "Steps for Adding a Sublist to a Form"
        } else {
          // Section Four - Output - Used in all sections
    
          var delimiter = /\u0001/;
          var sourceField = context.request.parameters.custpage_source;
          var parentField = context.request.parameters.custpage_parent_transaction;
    
          var invoiceRecord = record.load({
            type: record.Type.INVOICE,
            id: parentField,
          });
          log.debug("parent record", invoiceRecord);
    
          //   context.response.write(
          //     "You have entered:" + "<br/>  Name: " + sourceField
          //   );
          var recObj = record.create({
            type: "customrecord_user_notes",
          });
          recObj.setValue({ fieldId: "custrecord_source", value: sourceField });
          recObj.setValue({
            fieldId: "custrecord_parent_transaction",
            value: parentField,
          });
          var userNote = recObj.save({});
    
          var notesFieldUpdate = record.submitFields({
            type: record.Type.INVOICE,
            id: parentField,
            values: {
              custbody_notes_check:
                "<span style='color:#e74c3c;'>Check Notes</span>",
            },
          });
          log.debug("notesfield", notesFieldUpdate);
          // context.response.write((location, "_self").close());
    
          context.response.write("Note Created");
          context.response.write("<script>window.close();</script>");
    
          // var close_form = serverWidget.createForm({
          //   id: "close_form",
          //   title: "close form",
          // });
          // close_form.clientScriptFileId = 2637;
          // context.response.writePage(close_form);
        }
      }
      return {
        onRequest: onRequest,
      };
    });
```